# Postgres does not use HASH index while creating query plan

Tags: postgresql, join, query-optimization, postgresql-9.1, sql-execution-plan

I have created an **HASH index** on table **t_posts** on column topics_id which is the primary key in table **t_topics**

```
select * FROM t_topics
 JOIN t_posts ON  t_topics.topics_id = t_posts.topics_id
```

When I execute above query the plan generated

```
Hash Join  (cost=12258.02..346305.42 rows=1813743 width=520)
  Hash Cond: (t_posts.topics_id = t_topics.topics_id)
  ->  Seq Scan on t_posts  (cost=0.00..114209.43 rows=1813743 width=408)
  ->  Hash  (cost=5939.12..5939.12 rows=217112 width=112)"
        ->  Seq Scan on t_topics  (cost=0.00..5939.12 rows=217112 width=112)
```

[image]

Where as the plan should be sequentially scanning t_topics and the use the HASH index on t_posts for *t_topics* and perform JOIN. Why is the query plan generated like this?

Comment: What datatype are `topics_id` columns? What data do you have there?

Comment: You are select **all** columns and **all** rows from both tables. A sequential scan on both tables is the most efficient thing to do here. Using the index would actually make things slower.

Comment: @Boris columns are integer types

Answer (score 2):

This index would only help in a *nested loop join*, but the planner chooses to perform a *hash join*, where an index on the join condition is no help.
Judging from the row count estimates, I'd say that the planner is right.

You can check if your index could be used by a nested loop join by setting `enable_hashjoin` and `enable_mergejoin` to `off` and trying again.